# Desarrollando una funcion lowerCase/upperCase

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo programando. Estoy tratando de implementar un ejercicio (es académico) que haga lo siguiente:

**EJERCICIO OBLIGATORIO**

PRE: Recibe un string palabra.
POS: Retorna un nuevo string con el case Invertido. Es decir si un caracter es lowercase debe pasar a ser uppercase y viceversa.

Se pueden utilizar funciones auxiliares, pero no funciones de bibliotecas de C/C++ (como strcpy, toupper, tolower etc.).

Ejemplo 1
Entrada: "hola"
Retorno: "HOLA"

Ejemplo 2
Entrada: "Write IN C"
Retorno: "wRITE in c"

---

Esto es lo que pude hacer hasta el momento y esta la salida que estoy obteniendo; entiendo que me falta agregar el caracter \0 al final de retorno pero continúo con problemas en la salida:

Prueba Invertir Case de palabra 1 -> ERROR salida incorrecta

```
Parametros de entrada: 
Se esperaba: 
Se recibio:  Э§§§§нннб9a
```

Prueba Invertir Case de palabra 2 -> ERROR salida incorrecta

```
Parametros de entrada: hola
Se esperaba: HOLA
Se recibio:  ЭЭЭЭЭ§§§§
```

Prueba Invertir Case de palabra 3 -> ERROR salida incorrecta

```
Parametros de entrada: Write in C
Se esperaba: wRITE IN c
Se recibio:  ЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ§§§§
```

El código de la función es el siguiente:

```
char* invertirCase(char* palabra) {
  char* retorno = new char[largo(palabra)+1];
  int i = 0;

  while (palabra[i] != '\0') {
    if (palabra[i]>= 'A' && (palabra[i] )<= 'Z') {
      palabra[i] += 32;
    }
    i++;
    if (palabra[i] >= 'a' && palabra[i] <= 'z') {
      palabra[i] -= 32;
    }
    i++;
  }
  //retorno[i] = '\0';
  return retorno;
}

//Función auxiliar para calcular el largo de mi String.
unsigned int largo(const char* str)
{
    int tamanio = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        tamanio++;
    }
    return(tamanio);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiremos de la base de que la funcion `largo()` funciona correctamente (como no la has incluido no lo podemos saber).

El principal error que tienes es que **escribes en `palabra`** en vez de en `retorno`. Lo qu estás devolviendo es una cadena sin inicializar.

Por otro lado, nota que incrementas `i` sin venir a cuento:

```
while (palabra[i] != '\0') {
  if (palabra[i]>= 'A' && (palabra[i] )<= 'Z') {
    palabra[i] += 32;
  }
  i++; // <<--- AQUI
  if (palabra[i] >= 'a' && palabra[i] <= 'z') {
    palabra[i] -= 32;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Ese incremento evitará que conviertas a mayúscula las letras pares y a minúscula las impares.

El último error que tienes es que nunca pretendes finalizar la cadena, luego es más que probable que cualquier resultado imprima caracteres basura.

Una posible solución:

```
int i = 0;
char c;
do
{
  c = palabra[i];
  if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )
    c += 'a' - 'A';
  else if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
    c -= 'a' - 'A';

  retorno[i] = c;
  i++;
} while( c != '\0');
```

Comment: Ha solucionado el problema! Muchas gracias @eferion!!!! Gracias por enseñarme.